# C# WPF Read/Edit CSV

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, csv, xaml

I am currently writing an application in WPF C# that is some kind of helper for other processes which are written in Java. Those other processes require a configuration.csv in which different "names" are listed with a column that says "SKIP". If the column is X at Skip, my java program will skip those names and therefore their dependent processes.

If I open the CSV with Excel and edit the rows, everything works perfectly fine. That's not the problem. What I want to achieve is to list the rows into a DataGrid in a WPF App (except the first and last row), where the user can tick a checkbox to decide if he wants to skip that specific name or not. By pressing Save, the .CSV gets updated.

I already wrote some code with a friend who's more familiar with this topic. It worked fine in WinForms but doesn't work on WPF. We are not able to get the values of the checkboxes and not able to save them into the CSV.

CODE:

```
    private void OBJ_SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (OBJ_DataGrid.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Kein Datensatz in der View.");
            return;
        }
        /*if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                string tmp = null;
                try
                {
                    FileStream fileStr = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create);
                    StreamWriter strWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStr);
                    strWriter.WriteLine("SFObject;Skip");
                    for(int i=0;i< itmGrd.Count;i++)
                    {
                        switch (itmGrd[i].ItemValue)
                        {
                            case true:
                                tmp = itmGrd[i].ItemName + ";X";
                                break;
                            case false:
                                tmp = itmGrd[i].ItemName + ";";
                                break;
                        }
                        strWriter.WriteLine(tmp);
                    }
                    strWriter.WriteLine("SuccessMSG;");
                    strWriter.Close();
                    fileStr.Close();
                    LoadConf();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("ERR_F0: Pfad nicht gefunden.");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("ERR_D0: Pfad nicht gefunden.");*/
    }

    private void OBJ_ReloadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void OBJ_DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void OBJ_DataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Row.ToString());
    }

    void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Source.ToString());
    }


}

public class ItemGrid
{
    public ItemGrid(string name, bool rval)
    {
        ItemName = name;
        ItemValue = rval;
    }

    public string ItemName { set; get; }
    public bool ItemValue { set; get; }
}

public class ItemsGrid : List<ItemGrid>
{
    public string path = null;
    public string filepath = null;
    public ItemsGrid()
    {
        path = String.Format(@"{0}\build\", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        filepath = Path.Combine(path + "configuration.csv");
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                string line = null;
                StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filepath);
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (!line.Equals("SFObject;Skip") && !line.Equals("SuccessMSG;"))
                    {
                        string input = (line.IndexOf(";X") != -1 ? (line.Replace(";X", "")) : (line.Replace(";", "")));
                        Add(new ItemGrid(input, (line.IndexOf(";X") != -1 ? (true) : (false))));
                    }
                }
                file.Close();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("ERR_F0: Pfad nicht gefunden.");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("ERR_D0: Pfad nicht gefunden.");


        //Add(new ItemGrid("Tom", false));
        // Add(new ItemGrid("Jen", false));

    }

}
```

This is how it looks (and should look like).
[image: Image1]

CSV:

[image: Image2]

I hope that you guys can help me out, I really don't understand why it's not working. I also have to admit that I am not any near of being proficient in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the CSV you pasted is considered properly formatted.

```
// HelperClass.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfCsvSkipTicker
{
    public static class HelperClass
    {
        public static  List<ItemGrid> ReadCsv(string filepath)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(filepath)) return null;
            var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
            var result =
                from line in allLines.Skip(1).Take(allLines.Length -2)
                let temparry = line.Split(';')
                let isSkip =
                    temparry.Length > 1
                    && temparry[1] != null
                    && temparry[1] == "X"
                select new ItemGrid { ItemName = temparry[0], ItemValue = !isSkip };
            return result.ToList();
        }

        public static void WriteCsv(IEnumerable<ItemGrid> items, string filepath)
        {
            var temparray = items.Select(item => item.ItemName + ";" + (item.ItemValue ? "" : "X")).ToArray();
            var contents = new string[temparray.Length + 2];
            Array.Copy(temparray, 0, contents, 1, temparray.Length);
            contents[0] = "SFOBject;Skip";
            contents[contents.Length - 1] = "SuccessMSG;";
            File.WriteAllLines(filepath, contents);
        }
    }

    public class ItemGrid
    {
        public string ItemName { set; get; }
        public bool ItemValue { set; get; }
    }
}
```

And...

```
// MainWindow.xaml.cs 
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGridView.ItemsSource = HelperClass.ReadCsv(@"PathToRead\configuration.csv");
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var temp = new List<ItemGrid>();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.dataGridView.Items[i] is ItemGrid) // DataGrid pads it's item collection with elements we didn't add.
                temp.Add((ItemGrid)this.dataGridView.Items[i]);
        }
        HelperClass.WriteCsv(temp, @"PathToSave\new_configuration.csv");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @WithMetta , thank you so much for this! Everything works perfectly fine now. Got the first Demo in two hours and the application is done now! Thanks Thanks Thanks!!!